# Curses Module Eroor in Python

Tags: python, module, curses

i try to import curses but when i run the program it shows this error

```
    import random
    import curses

    s = curses.initscr()
    curses.curs_set(0)
    sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
    w = curses.newin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
    w.keypad(1)

    w.timeout(100)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'

Comment: On what operating system are you programming?

Comment: windows 10 @jpuriol

Answer (score 0):

The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module. There are some ports for windows like [windows-curses](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/) that implement the same API. You should install one of those modules.